# Controlling a series of LEDs ( AC->DC via bridge rectifier)

Tags: power-supply, led, pcb-design, ac, led-driver

I'm working on a PCB (Christmas Present) to take in A/C to a string of LEDs and control them (with transistors? and a microcontroller). This is a bit out of my league, but it is making me learn quickly. As far as I can tell this should work, but that is a weak statement at best, I'd appreciate any guidance.

My first crack at this, which I have successfully built and it runs stably is just lighting the LEDs. It looks like:

[image: Current Circuit Design]

Now I'm trying to add another (far more complex) layer to this, by making the LEDs controllable. The design I've come up with is:

[image: Design Idea #1]

But I have a ton of uncertainty about this. These are my concerns / questions:

1. The voltage will be entirely difference for every connection on the microcontroller -> Transistor (base).
2. Is there additional protection needed for the microcontroller's GPIO. I think they would only be in output mode, I just need to pull to ground to switch off the transistor. I've seen suggestions of putting a resistor and/or Zener Diode inline, but that was only in the context of using the pins for input.

Am I even close to having a working design?

Comment: 1) no, you're not close to having a working design. 2) if you have little experience with electronics, you should ***absolutely not*** be working with anything connected to mains power

Comment: referring to the second schematic ... the voltage between the group #1 transistor base and the group #65 transistor base can be in the neighborhood of 170 Vdc

Comment: Your circuit is a disaster. But forget that... You show a transistor on each LED, does that means you want to control each one individually ie. 64 x 3 = 192 LEDs each with a separate control?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I would probably only control about 1/3, just remove the transistors from the other 2/3.

Comment: So that's 64 strings of 3 LEDs each?

Comment: Do NOT build that circuit! On the other hand, you can buy a reasonable 5V DC power supply, a microcontroller (or an Arduino, probably the Nano could be closest to your needs), and a WS2812B-based LED strip. You connect the power supply to AC, the 5V part to the LEDs and the Arduino, connect a digital pin to the 1st LED's input, and you're done. The software side just import the Neopixel library, come up with a pattern to show, program it, and you're done.

Comment: That cct will kill your controller, some or all of the LEDs and Rs and, possibly, you. Tell us what you are trying to achieve and we can help you do it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the week was consumed by work. Thanks for the guidance, I appreciate it. So the whole project is a Christmas gift, PCB Christmas tree ornament. I wanted to hook it up inline with the Christmas lights, which are AC. The number of LEDs doesn't really matter to me, I just chose 64 because that accounted for the proper voltage drop.